# Recovering deleted Telegram chat

Tags: telegram, chat-history

On my new Android phone I accidentally (yes...) deleted a complete chat I never exported before. Looking for ways to recover it I didn't find the ultimate solution. While I could restore the chat pictures (they weren't actually deleted) I couldn't find a way to restore the messages which are far more important to me.

I still have my old Android phone that I used until a month ago that never connected to the Internet since I deleted the chat. So, if the messages are somehow stored locally, it still has the deleted chat (obviously but for the last month, but that would be better than losing everything). I didn't dare to start the device since the chat loss as I want to understand the implications first.

- Does Telegram store the chat messages locally or only on the server?
- If storing them locally, how can I export them? I guess I need an internet-less solution as a synchronization would obviously delete the chat on my old phone as well. I could only find the Desktop-Telegram-based export, but no other suitable solution.

I'm afraid I guess I'll get a "you're screwed" answer but I want to give the community a last chance to help me before eventually giving up hope.

Comment: it is usually stored local and synchronized online. make a full rom dump of your old phone before (download or recovery mode). then switch to airplane mode as soon as phone starts up. If you are paranoid, you can unplug your wifi router and hold phone in microwave oven while doing this